# How to fix tab switching and applet?

Tags: java, browser, tabs, applet, japplet

When I launch a JApplet (contained in a self-signed JAR) I built through a web browser, none of the Components (buttons/labels) show up until I switch tabs and back.  It works perfectly with appletviewer, so I'm quite lost at what the problem is and how I can fix it.  Thanks!

Comment: I suspect I could explain why it works in applet viewer, but I don't like making random guesses.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: After a little bit of fiddling around I found out the applet works perfectly on Internet Explorer, somewhat on Firefox, and only shows the background (no buttons) on Chrome.  How strange!

Comment: You have ignored my advice.  How unproductive!